# Re-enable Wi-Fi on a Time Capsule

Tags: time-capsule, airport

I have a Time Capsule that normally acts as a Wireless bridge to my DSL router. (All DHCP and NAT takes place on the router, not the Time Capsule.)

During debugging of home networking issues, I created a new wireless network on the router (it has its own antennae, etc.) and I used the Airport Utility to turn the Wireless off on my Time Capsule.

I'm now connected to the network via the router, and want to return to the previous setup. However, the Airport Utility can no longer connect to the Time Capsule. It's like it cannot find it on the network.

How can I turn Wi-Fi back on?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Ethernet to connect to a Time Capsule with Wi-Fi disabled.

1. Connect Time Capsule and Mac via Ethernet cable.
2. Launch Airport Utility. If Wi-Fi on the Time Capsule is disabled it will show up with a yellow warning sign. Clicking on it only offers to 'Forget this device'.[image: Wi-Fi]
3. Click on 'Other Wi-Fi Devices' in the top left corner and under 'Network Interfaces', choose 'Ethernet'.
   [image: Ethernet]
4. The Time Capsule should appear. Clicking on it now allows to change its 'Network Mode' by first hitting 'Edit', then choosing the 'Wireless' tab, followed by selecting Wi-Fi from the dropdown menu. Applying the settings will take a few seconds and require a restart.
   [image: Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Be patient. After approximately 10 minutes (!) with the new setup the Airport Utility was finally able to find the Time Capsule under the new configuration.